# My Ubuntu VM gets a Kernel Panic UNLESS I start with Linux 5.4.0-58

Tags: boot, kernel, virtualbox, crash

I'm fairly novice when it comes to Linux and VM things, so excuse my ignorance, please :)

So I had a simple up-to-date Ubuntu VM that worked flawlessly, until one day past, I shut it down, and when the next day came, it wouldn't boot and came up with a "Failed to send host log message" error.

The suggested fix on the internet was to change the graphics controller in virtualbox from VMSVGA to VBoxSVGA, but doing brought up a whole different error message:

```
[...]
Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
Kernel Offset: 0x4600000 from 0xffffffff81000000 [etc]
```

And if that alone would not be weird enough, I found that if I change the Linux version using "Advanced options for Ubuntu" in GRUB to the oldest available there (Linux 5.4.0-58-generic), the VM can start up again just fine, regardless of graphics controller.

[Picture of my Grub Screen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkRWF.png)

I'm a bit lost as to what to do and where to find further logs, so I'm asking for your help here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What other kernel versions are present?  This sounds like the kernel and the VBox drivers don't match or work together.  (Can you screenshot the list of kernels you have on the VM?)

Comment: @ThomasWard https://imgur.com/a/JDIg5Vp
Both VirtualBox and what I could do in the older Linux version is fully updated.

Comment: There are known problems with the 5.8 kernels, and packages not undergoing tests behind the scenes when that kernel got pushed.  You may want to stick to the 5.4 kernel for now and manually boot to the 5.4 kernel for now until they fix the problems.

Comment: @ThomasWard well what I find weird is that, at least the 5.8.0-38 used to work fine on that machine. Anyhow, is there any way where I can make it so it boots into the 5.4 one by default? Thanks!

Comment: you can login with the 5.4 shell and remove `linux-image-*5.8.0*` kernels with `sudo apt remove 'linux-image-*5.8.0*'` - this will remove the 5.8.0 kernels and force you to use 5.4 that's already installed.

Comment: the Kernel team would like you to file a bug on this at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe-5.8 if you could.  Basically provide what you stated here and any additional commands and output that they request there after you file.

Answer (score 0):

I filed a bug about this issue:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe-5.8/+bug/1913881

rappluk, please add your host hardware information to the bug. This affects my Ryzen 9 system, but an Intel Core i7 system is not affected.

As a workaround, you may select the 5.4 kernel through GRUB. Then the system works fine.

Comment: This issue appears fixed for me after Cumulative Updates for Windows 10 20H2 and .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.5 on February 9, 2021.  The bug has been updated.